# Effcient algorithm to find one specific solution and amount of solutions of a Diophantine equation with 3 variables

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, equation

I'm trying to make an efficient algorithm in C++/C to find one (any) solution and the amount of solutions of a Diophantine equation `Ax+By+Cz=D` where `A,B,C,D` are integers given by the user and `x,y,z` run on a range given by the user. `x,y,z` are integers as well.

I don't want to use the brute force method by doing 3 nested loops as it's O(n^3).

So the first thing in the algorithm is to find out if there are solutions:

```
Ax+By=gcd(A,B)

gcd(A,B)w+Cz=gcd(gcd(A,B),C)
```

Lastly, if `gcd(gcd(A,B),C)` divides `D` then there are solutions.

I can do that, but now I'm back to square one... I'm trying to find references on how to do it for hours but all I find is either brute force or an algorithm for 2 variables, or in a language I don't know...

Comment: Why are you back to square 1? If r*gcd(gcd(A,B),C) = D (as you've found): Then Axrw+Byrw+Czr=D doesn't it? Home and dry by the looks of it! At least in finding A solution anyway.

Comment: @DanAllen please see my comment for the answer below.

Comment: There are either no solutions or infinitely many solutions.

Comment: @tmyklebu, no it's bounded in a range.

Comment: @kuhaku: Huh?  Where did you say that?

Comment: @tmyklebu "x,y,z run on a range given by the user. x,y,z are integers as well."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem to find the amount of solutions of a Diophantine equation `Ax+By+Cz=D` is equal to [Coin Change Problem](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Coin_Change) with sum D and coin denominations A,B,C.
It could be solved by dynamic programming (taking into account limited ranges of x,y,z). DP gives also solutions of equation.

Comment: I'm pretty new to programing, what does dynamic programing actually means in this context?

Comment: In general, dynamic programming divides problem to subproblems and solves larger ones using solutions of smaller ones. Example - if we have solution for sum value D-A (triplet x,y,z), we can obtain solution for sum value D as (x+1,y,z)

Answer (score 1):

use [Extended Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm). There is not much to say, the link say it all. And also you already break the question and make it simple `Ax+By=gcd(A,B)` quesion.

Comment: I saw that, it doesn't work: 
For example: `2x-3y-z=5` in range `[-2,2]` I know that it has 6 solutions but when I use that method I get: `gcd (2,3)=1` then `w-z=5` but this equation has no solutions in `[-2,2]`.

Comment: @kuhaku yeah you are right, I dont consider that, I'll think about that and if I solve this will update my answer